# Link to a question, answer, or comment

Tags: support, hyperlinks

In writing a question, answer, or comment, how can I include a clickable link that cross-references another question, answer, or comment at English Language & Usage SE?

What I found through  **help**  at EL&U and as questions at EL&U Meta were:

- [How to reference material written by
  others](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing)
- [What's the best way to answer when there's a really good answer
  elsewhere?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/153448)
- [I'd like to be able to provide simplified hyperlinks in my answers but
  do not know how](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4213/153448)

These are helpful in various ways but do not touch on the mechanics of obtaining a good link address (URL) for the target posting.

<sub>(This question is here to facilitate access to information,
 in accordance with
 [Stack Exchange policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).)</sub>

Comment: This is an elementary question answered in the FAQs

Answer (score -1):

This question has been answered at Meta Stack Exchange:

[Link to a question, answer or
 comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272427/313009)

<sub>(This answer is a plant to facilitate access to information, in accordance with
[Stack Exchange policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).)</sub>

Comment: Wait...you're answering your own question, which you know to be a dupe? Is this a winter bash hat for that for _next_ year

Comment: Usually though this type of answer is a response to one or more requests for help. I haven't seen any that ask about how to link back to a post. I mean... if you know how to "surf" on the Internet, you should also know how to copy'n'paste a link... and you should know what the words "share", "edit" and "flag" mean.  Nonetheless, the easiest tutorials to follow, I find, are [the ones with images](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/7449/is-there-any-way-i-could-follow-a-question-asked-by-someone-else/7484#7484), especially helpful if you happen to be a non native speaker.

Comment: URLs that link directly to comments are effectively hidden in the dates of comments. Users at EL&U *have* asked, in comments, and I had to figure it out from HTML code. Stack Exchange encourages contribution by all experts in a field, not just those who are web savvy